# How to solve this combinatorial problem correctly?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:** Ten different candies are given to three children `A`, `B` and `C`. each child has at least one. How many different ways are there?

I use two different methods to solve this problem:

```
    f[1, n_] := n;
    f[n_, 1] := 1;
    f[n_, m_] := f[n, m] = m (f[n - 1, m - 1] + f[n - 1, m])
    
    f[10, 3]
```

```
    Select[Tuples[Range[3], 10], Length[Union[#]] == 3 &] // Length
```

But the result of the first method is not equal to `StirlingS2[10, 3] 3!`. I want to know how to solve this problem correctly?

Comment: It is not even clear what is being asked. How many outcomes if the candies are distinguishable? How many if the candies are identical?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau My original intention is that these ten candies are different. Of course, these two situations can be discussed together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[1, m_ /; m > 1] = 0;
f[n_ /; n >= 1, 1] = 1;
f[n_, m_] := f[n, m] = m (f[n - 1, m - 1] + f[n - 1, m]); TableForm[
 MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, 
  Table[f[m, n], {m, 1, 10}, {n, 1, 10}], {10, 3}], 
 TableHeadings -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solve it:

1- Use `FrobeniusSolve` to find all possible solutions (how many candies each kid gets):

```
FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1, 1}, 10]

(*Out: {{0, 0, 10}, {0, 1, 9}, {0, 2, 8}, {0, 3, 7}, ...} *)
(*Output Length: 66 *)
```

2- Since each kid should gets at least one candy, filter the possibilities contain zero:

```
ps = DeleteCases[FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1, 1}, 10], l_ /; MemberQ[l, 0]];

(*Out: {{1, 1, 8}, {1, 2, 7}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, ...} *)
(*Output Length: 36 *)
```

- To create a list like yours that specify which candy goes to which kid, I use `MapIndexed`, for example:

```
Flatten[MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2, #1] &, {1, 8, 1}]]
(*Out: {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3} *)
```

- For finding out how many ways you can distribute in `{1,8,1}` format, I use `Permutations` which produces all the tuples without duplicate:

```
Length[Permutations[Flatten[MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2, #1] &, {1, 8, 1}]]]]
(*Out: 90 *)
```

3- Now just apply previous steps to all the possibilities stored in `ps` and sum it up:

```
Sum[Length[Permutations[Flatten[MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2, #1] &, i]]]], {i,ps}]

(*Out: 55980 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the definition of StirlingS2 (not showing conditions of having positive integers):

```
stirling[n_, m_] := (1/m!) Sum[(-1)^(m - k) Binomial[m, k] k^n, {k, 0, m}]
stirling[10,3]
(* 9330 *)
```

Removing the factor (1/m!), you get:

```
f[n_, m_] := Sum[(-1)^(m - k) Binomial[m, k] k^n, {k, 0, m}]
f[10,3]
(* 55980 *)
```